# Demonstrate if a language is regular

Tags: theory, computation

I have to demonstrate the regularity of the following language: {xy ∈ {a,b}* | |X|<sub>a</sub> = 2|Y| <sub>b</sub>} which refers to words of the form xy where the number of occurrences of a in subword x is twice the number of occurrences of b in subword y. I suspect that it is regular but I don't know how to demonstrate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably https://mathoverflow.net/ is better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The language:

```
{ xy in {a,b}* such that |x|a = 2|y|b }
```

Consider strings in the language `(aa)* = {e, aa, aaaa, ...}`. We will show that each of these strings is distinguishable by the Myhill-Nerode theorem's indistinguishability relation. This implies any DFA for the language must have infinitely many states, a contradiction.

The shortest string that takes `e` to a string not in the language is `ab`. The shortest string that takes `aa` to a string not in the language is `abb`. The shortest string that takes `aaaa` to a string not in the language is `abbb`. In general, the shortest string that takes `a^(2n)` to a string not in the language is `ab^(n+1)`. Such a string will be of the form `a^(2n+1) b^(n+1)` which is missing a single `a` to be in the language. Every string of the form `(aa)*` would need to lead a minimal `DFA` for this language to a state different from all the others.

Another way to see this is with closure properties. Regular languages are closed under intersection. Take the intersection of this language with the regular language `a(aa)*b*`. Now the condition `|x|a = 2|y|b` can clearly be satisfied if and only if `|w|a > 2|w|b`.

- if `|w|a = 2|w|b` is impossible since we have an odd number of `a`s
- if `|w|a > 2|w|b`, choose `x` to have length equal to `2|w|b`. `y` will have some extra `a`s, but that's OK.
- if `|w|a < 2|w|b`, we would need to have some `b`s to the left of the split, but that is impossible since we have an odd number of `a`s on the left whenever we split to the right of the `a`s.

The language with this condition (odd number of `a`s, followed by `b`s, with more than twice as many `a`s as `b`s) is not a regular language. To see this, we can use the string `a^(2p+1) b^(p+1)` and the pumping lemma for regular languages to argue that pumping can reduce the number of `a`s without changing the number of `b`s.

Comment: I don't understand because you say that number of a's will be reduced. Using pumping lema the number of a's always will be increased, won't it?

Comment: @Paul94 The idea of the pumping Lemma supports this since a string of length more than p causes the minimal DFA of p states to enter some state twice, so you could always remove the duplication rather than extend it. (n = 0, skipping the loop, must be a valid path through the machine).